# Do dense complements in $\mathbb{R}$, which are uncountable, both contain a rational number?

Tags: set-theory

Suppose $D$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$ are both dense in $\mathbb{R}$. If they are both uncountable, do both sets then necessarily have to contain a rational number?

Comment: Well, consider each set intersected with the irrationals, then union only one of the two with the rationals.

Comment: @Joe That doesn't really help... I was thinking that since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$ are both dense, we could somehow get new sets by taking some irrationals and adding them to $\mathbb{Q}$. Then both would be dense but only one would contain any rationals

Comment: Partition $X=\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$ into two disjoint, uncountable subsets $A,B$. Then $D=\mathbb{Q}\cup A$ with $\mathbb{R}\backslash D=B$ will be your counterexample.

Comment: @freakish is $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$ then still dense? Because if we take those disjoint sets to be the irrationals smaller than $0$ and those larger than $0$ then $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$  isn't dense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No.

First, note that for all infinite cardinals $\kappa$, we have $\kappa + \kappa = \kappa$. Therefore, we can find $A, B$ disjoint such that $|A| = |B| = |\mathbb{R}|$ and $A \cup B = \mathbb{R}$.

Now choose a countable dense set $C$ with no rationals - perhaps $C = \{x + \sqrt{2} \mid x \in \mathbb{Q}\}$ for concrete ness.

Define $D = A \cup \mathbb{Q} \setminus C$. Then define $E = \mathbb{R} \setminus D = B \cup C \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then $D$ and its complement $E$ are both dense, uncountable sets, but $E$ has no rationals.

Comment: This is what I was alluding to in the comments, but I couldn't find a specific example. Cheers!

Comment: Sometimes it can be hard to give an explicit construction of an uncountable set with certain properties. An example that comes to mind is to let F be the set of irrational Liouville numbers and let G be the rest of the irrational reals. F and G are dense and each has the cardinal of the reals.

Comment: A Q for the readers in  Amer. Math. Monthly was "A student asserted that an uncountable set of reals contains a closed uncountable subset. Is this true?" ...  My first thought was that it's likely true that a student asserted it. But of course it means "If $S \subset \Bbb R$ and $S$ is uncountable, must there exist $T\subset S$  where $T$ is uncountable and $T$ is closed in $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Another way of doing this is to construct an explicit bijection $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} + \mathbb{R}$ by pushing along a definable bijection $\mathbb{R} \cong 2^\mathbb{N}$ and noting $2^\mathbb{N} \cong 2^{1 + \mathbb{N}} \cong 2 \times 2^\mathbb{N} \cong 2^\mathbb{N} + 2^\mathbb{N}$.