# Proving a topological space defined by a certain base is separable

Tags: general-topology

Suppose we have $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean topology $T$. If $D$ is a dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\mathbb{R} \setminus D $ is also dense in $\mathbb{R}$, consider the collection $\mathcal{B}$ of sets $\{x\} \cup (D \cap U) $ where $x \in U$ and $U \in T$. This collection forms a basis for a new topology $\mathcal{T}^*$.

I want to prove that $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{T}^*)$ is separable. For this I need to prove that there exists a countable set that is dense in $\mathbb{R}$. This is easy if $D$ or $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$ is countable. However, I'm stuck for the case where both $D$ and $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$ are uncountable. I tried looking at $\mathbb{Q}$ in this case, but that didn't seem to work (see for example a previous question of mine: [Do dense complements in $\mathbb{R}$, which are uncountable, both contain a rational number?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454452/do-dense-complements-in-mathbbr-which-are-uncountable-both-contain-a-rati/4454467#4454467)).

Comment: Do you know for sure it is separable, eg it has been left as an exercise?

Comment: Neither $D$ nor its complement has to be countable. But $D\cap \mathbb Q$ or $\mathbb Q\cap (\mathbb R \setminus D)$ is dense. Try to prove that these are dense in the new topology.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy how can I prove that those sets are dense?

Comment: @FShrike yes it was

Comment: I will post an alternative solution in a few hours

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{F}{\mathcal{F}}\newcommand{\G}{\mathcal{G}}\newcommand{\T}{\mathcal{T}}\newcommand{\B}{\mathcal{B}}$Perhaps I'm making a trivial error, but I think the hypothesis "$\Bbb R\setminus D$ is dense" is superfluous.

For an $n\in\Bbb N$, consider the partition: $$\Bbb R=\bigsqcup_{m\in\Bbb Z}\left[\frac{m}{n},\frac{m+1}{n}\right]$$Since $D$ is dense, one may extract an element of $D$, labelled $d_{n,m}$, from each of these intervals. If we perform this process for every $n\in\Bbb N$, we have the set: $$\F:=\{d_{n,m}:(n,m)\in\Bbb N\times\Bbb Z\}\subseteq D$$Which is a countable set. However, every single open $U\subseteq\Bbb R$ contains an interval of the form $[m/n,(m+1)/n]$ for some suitable $m$ and $n$. Therefore, $(D\cap U)\cap\F$ is never empty for an open $U$.

Comment: the condition that $\mathbb{R} \setminus D$ is important though, it eliminates the sets $D$ that are for example $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\}$ missing just one point.

Comment: @Geigercounter I am not seeing right now how that affects separability or the argument in my post

Comment: +1. This looks fine to me.